# How to see if the Windows Audit Service has been stopped?

Tags: windows, security

I'm looking to find something in the Windows Security logs that will tell me if auditing has been disabled - the idea being that if somebody wants to conceal their activity, they'll turn off the audit log, do whatever they want to, and then turn it back on.

I know that there is a Windows Security Event "1100: The event logging service has shut down" that happens normally during shutdown, but this doesn't seem to log if somebody turns it off. There's also no equivalent for Windows Server 2003.

Is there an event code in the Security logs (or System logs), that will tell me when somebody has manually turned off auditing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What is the event ID that identifies when auditing has been turned off?

You are looking for 4719: System audit policy was changed:

> This event is always logged when an audit policy is disabled, regardless of the "Audit Policy Change" sub-category setting. **This and several other events can help identify when someone attempts to disable auditing to cover their tracks**.

---

#### 4719: System audit policy was changed

> - This computer's system level audit policy was modified - either via Local Security Policy, Group Policy in Active Directory or the audipol
>     command.
> - According to Microsoft, this event is always logged when an audit policy is disabled, regardless of the "Audit Policy Change"
>     sub-category setting. This and several other events can help identify
>     when someone attempts to disable auditing to cover their tracks.
> - If group policy was used to configure audit policy unfortunately the Subject fields don't identify who actually changed the policy.  In
>     such cases this event always shows the local computer as the one who
>     changed the policy since the computer is the security principal under
>     which gpupdate runs.
> - If auditpol was used to configure audit policy will properly reflect the user in Subject:.
>
> **Subject**:
>
> The ID and logon session of the user that changed the policy - always
>   the local system - see note above.
>
> - Security ID:  The SID of the account.
> - Account Name: The account logon name.
> - Account Domain: The domain or - in the case of local accounts - computer name.
> - Logon ID is a semi-unique (unique between reboots) number that identifies the logon session.  Logon ID allows you to correlate
>     backwards to the logon event (4624) as well as with other events
>     logged during the same logon session.

See the source link below for a full list of Categories and Subcategories for the event.

Source [4719: System audit policy was changed](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4719)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Windows Security Log Events](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/Default.aspx?catid=2)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the event I need. Only trouble is, it doesn't seem to show up in my Event Log. I'm tracking "Audit Policy Changes", so I'm not sure why it isn't showing up in the Security Events. is there something else I'll need to configure to start seeing this event?